# Xcode run successful but got error when archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, archiving

My app write by Swift and Objective -C file. Everything OK when run app, but when I archive app, I got the error as the below image(The error file is Objective C file, and it use Swift code):
[image]

**Edit:** after many research and trying then flowing steps help me fix it:

- set **Enable Bitcode** into build settings to NO(it require with apple watch app but optional with iPhone app)
- In the build settings **Preprocessor Macros -> Release** add the target name match with the name of target into error file

Comment: Above Solution Worked perfectly with a little change.
While Archiving the target, Pre-Processor Macro is picked from 'Build Setting -> PreProcessor Macro -> Release'.
So We need to define the same Debug Macro to Release also.

Answer (score 0):

In my Swift project adding `use_frameworks!` into the `Podfile` did the trick. [I answered this in another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33594354/1633733)