# Xcode will build/run but archive fails with "No such module Google" - Swift iOS

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods, archive

My app has been working fine until Xcode 7.1. In fact, it still runs on both the simulator and iPhone, but when I archive it, I get the error "No such module Google." I have cocoa pods updated to 0.39 and have tried for hours with tweaking the options, from reinstalling cocoa pods to removing the Google Analytics cocoa pod and adding it manually, etc. However, nothing has worked, and whenever I *archive* the app, I receive an error, yet it still runs fine.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error. Do you have any solution now?

Comment: Turns out the issue was with Google Analytics for cocoa pods. I completely removed it and switched to Flurry.

Comment: I have the same error with twitterKit...

Comment: I haven't used twitterKit and I don't know any more information about the error itself because I just removed the Google Analytics cocoa pod completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with Google Analytics for cocoa pods. I completely removed the cocoapod and switched to Flurry.

Answer (score 0):

For me it turned out, that I had forgotten to put

```
use_frameworks!
```

into the `Podfile`. After adding this line and updating the pods it worked. Just make sure to `import` all modules in all depending classes.

Edit:
[Official blog resource from cocoapods](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)